# Induction to prove $2n + 3 < 2^n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, induction

I am having trouble and was wondering if someone could go over the steps slowly to show that:

$$2n + 3 < 2^n \ \text{for} \ n \geq 4$$

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Base case:** Just check it when $n=4$.

**Inductive step:** Suppose $2n+3 < 2^n$ for some $n$. Then it must be the case that $$2(2n+3) < 2 \times 2^n$$But what does this tell you?

**Hint:** Compare the left-hand side of this inequality with $2(n+1)+3$.

Comment: Why are we multiplying both sides by 2?

Comment: @hoping2learn: Because for the inductive step you want $2^{n+1}$ on the right-hand side, and $2^{n+1} = 2 \times 2^n$. (The inductive step is to show that *if* the statement holds for some $n$ *then* it holds when you replace $n$ by $n+1$. This is why I also mention $2(n+1)+3$.)

Comment: Okay I think I understand why its 2×2^n. So if I substitute n+1 in for n, how do I go about proving that it holds true, I guess my question is, what is the next step?

Comment: @hoping2learn: Expand the inequality I gave you. You'll see you end up with something which isn't what you want on the left-hand side. But what you have on the left-hand side is *bigger than* what you want, so you can stick another $<$ sign to the left of it and write down what you want (as long as you've convinced yourself this is actually true). Give it a try $-$ I'm not going to write down the answer for you but I'm happy to say whether what you've done is right or wrong.

Comment: Not sure if im heading in the right direction but this is what I have now, 2n + 5 < 4n + 6 < 2 * 2^n. Is that it for the proof?

Comment: Yup :) As long as you can convince yourself that what you've done is true.

Comment: Okay, awesome! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 0):

If $2^m>2m+3$

$2^{m+1}-2(m+1)-3>2(2m+3)-2(m+1)-3=4m+1>0$

Now, for $m=1,2^m-(2m+3)=2^1-(2+3)<0$

$$\cdots$$

For $m=3,2^m-(2m+3)=2^4-(2\cdot3+3)=0$

For $m=4,2^m-(2m+3)=2^4-(2\cdot4+3)>0$

Answer (score 0):

For the induction step, if $2n+3<2^n$ (and $n\ge 0$) then 
$$2(n+1)+3 = 2n+5 <4n+6=2(2n+3)<2\cdot 2^n=2^{n+1}.$$

Comment: How did we get from 2n + 5 to 4n + 6?